# Add a New [content type] on each content type

Tags: nodes, 7

I want to create a block and put it in the sidebar of each content type that says "Add a new [content type]" So if the user was viewing an article, it would have "Add a new article", if the user was viewing a car, it would say "add a new car" etc.

Obviously I could make a different block and then control their display via context, but I'd rather create one block that essentially always links to add/new/[content-type] where content-type is whatever is being viewed.

Is there a way to pass in this argument via context?

Answer (score 1):

In the hook that return the block content, call a function with a code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_node_add_link() {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if (!empty($node->type)) {
    $types = node_type_get_types();
    return l(t('Add a new @name', array('@name' => $types[$node->type]->name)), 'node/add/' str_replace('_', '-', $node->type));
  }

  return '';
}
```

The hook calling this function should always check the value returned from the function. In the case the showed page is not a node page, `menu_get_object()` doesn't return a node object, and this function returns an empty string.

Notice that every string shown in the user interface should be passed to [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7). When passing a string to `t()`, you should avoid concatenating string, but you should use the placeholders the function supports, as in the code I shown.

Answer (score 0):

In D6, you could use something like this snippet...

```
function create_another() {

  $node=menu_get_object();

  if (!empty($node->type)) {

    return l('Add a new ' . $node->type, 'node/add/' . str_replace('_', '-', $node->type));

  }

}
```

which, if used on a page displaying a full node, would return a link to node/add/`content type`.  In D7, `menu_get_object()` does the same thing, so you'd probably just have to change the actual link path.  Just be careful if you have _'s in your node type.  In D6 they need to be translated into -'s in the link above.  I'm not sure about D7.